# Передача данных с одной страницы на другую. django

Tags: python, django

Собственно говоря имеется страница загрузки файла.
После загрузки, в файле ищутся определенные данные, из которых формируется список.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать этот список на другую страницу?
django 1.9

Comment: странный вопрос, просто сохраняйте файл в базе(точнее там сохраняется путь до него) и выводите на нужной странице.

Answer (score 2):

```
def main_view(request):
    if some_condition:
    ......
    my_object
    .....
    return slave_view(my_object, request)
```

Не знаю насколько это рабочий вариант но попробовать стоит, еще как вариант это Сессии. Или в базу сохранять.